# Is there a JSHint setting for spacing when concatenating strings?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, string-formatting, code-formatting, jshint

I've checked [JSHint documentation](http://jshint.com/docs/options), but I can't find any setting which allows JSHint to report spacing issues when concatenating strings.

For example, I would like JSHint to report an error when the spacing is missing between the quotation and the plus symbol:

`var myString = "my"+"string";`

Correct code:

`var myString = "my" + "string";`

Comment: I think JSHint is more about possible coding errors rather than coding style, so I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not anymore. The `white` option that provided this check was [removed](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1358); consider using [JSCS](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs) for more style-focused validation.

Specifically, I believe you want [requireSpaceBeforeBinaryOperators](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs#requirespacebeforebinaryoperators) and its counterpart [requireSpaceAfterBinaryOperators](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs#requirespaceafterbinaryoperators).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into JSCS.